# Linux use disk as ram for a process

Tags: linux, memory

I want to know if it's possible on linux to specify for a process to use disk as RAM. For exemple create a file and tell to a program to use this file as RAM.

Thanx

Comment: *"... if it's possible on linux to specify for a process to use disk as RAM ..."* - No. Programs execute from memory. There's no way to avoid memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the manpage for the `mmap(2)` syscall. Note that if just need "more memory" then using a swap file or swap partition is much, much easier.

*EDIT: Tried to come up with simple and easy demonstrator code and seems like it's not that easy to implement per process swap limits, without falling down a syscall rabbit hole.*